# Why can't I retrieve the value for parameters of type out or ref using Type.InvokeMember?

Tags: c#, reflection, reference-parameters

A long title, but I wanted it to be specific.  The title is really the question.  Even though the method that `InvokeMember` is calling has an `out` parameter and is assigning a value to to that parameter I can't grab that value.  Here is the code I was initially using:

```
string parameter = "";
int result = Convert.ToInt32(typeof(Ability).InvokeMember(selectedMove, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, null, new object[] { parameter }));
```

I changed it this, which now makes it work as intended but I don't know why:

```
object[] args = new object[1];      //necessary to retrieve ref/out parameter
int result = Convert.ToInt32(typeof(Ability).InvokeMember(selectedMove, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, null, args));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first code example, the call to `InvokeMember` doesn't modify the value of the `parameter` variable, it just replaces the first item in the parameter array (which now points to a different `string` instance). Since you didn't keep a reference to this array, you can't retrieve the value of the output parameter.

In other words: the array initially contains a copy of the `parameter` variable (i.e. a copy of the reference to an empty string). After the call, `parameter` and the value in the array refer to 2 different string instances.

Answer (score 10):

I just wanted to help someone who is struggling(I did) with unmanaged(COM) and getting ref-parameter back. So, when using InvokeMember against COM-method, you have to tell which arguments are ref-type. This is achieved by using ParameterModifier-class, For example:

```
object[] args = new object[3] { param1, param2, errorStr };
ParameterModifier pMod = new ParameterModifier(3);
pMod[2] = true;            
ParameterModifier[] mods = { pMod };

object tempObj = myCOMObject.GetType().InvokeMember("MyCOMMethod", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public, null, myCOMObject, args, mods, null, null);
```

In the code above, the 3rd argument is set to be a reference (pMod[2] = true;)

Answer (score 6):

Your second snippet is missing a rather essential line of code.  It should look like this, assuming the *out* argument is of type string:

```
object[] args = new object[1];      //necessary to retrieve ref/out parameter
int result = Convert.ToInt32(typeof(Ability).InvokeMember(selectedMove, 
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, 
    null, null, args));
string outValue = (string)args[0];  // <===  here!
```

It should now also be obvious why your 1st snippet cannot work, you don't have a reference to the object[] array that you pass so you can never retrieve the modified argument.